# Autofiltering by criteria1

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

After applying autofilter my data are not shown.

If I apply the same filter by hand, the data are shown correctly.

```vb
Private Sub FilteringReport()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\benesjan\Desktop\Benes_jan\Excel_VBA\test_file\preventive_report.xlsx"
    Workbooks("preventive_report.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    
    'Todays date, or custom date
    If Workbooks("PMM_reports.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        edate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").Value
    Else
        uedate = Now()
        edate = Format(uedate, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    End If
            
    MsgBox edate
    
    'edate is 10.08.2022
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A:J").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=""
        .Range("A:J").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<" & edate
    End With 
  
End Sub
```

I am filtering this table
[image: Excel table]

The first filter works and returns
[image]

After I apply the second filter I get
[image]

If I manually click ok, it reapplies it and it refreshes itself and starts working. Refreshing the whole workbook or reapplying the filters does not work, even recorded macro does not work.

Comment: Try `"<" & cDbl(edate)` in the line `.Range("A:J").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<" & edate`

Comment: Well, I got "Type mismatch" converting to double is not it, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: *I got "Type mismatch" converting to double is not it* Are those dates real dates or text? Maybe the problem is the datatype

Comment: The dates that are filtered are dates, the value I filter with might not be, but it is taken as a value from callendar. Will try to filter by a real concrete date data type and post my progress.

Comment: Ok. I tried to work with just a string, did not work, converting "10.08.2022" to double is just impossible, date is not a number. One thing, that worked was trying the filter by equals, that worked like so  `"=" & edate` . I run out of ideas of what to do.

Comment: USe the other variable. What about `"<" & cDbl(uedate) `?

Comment: uedate worked, the filter is working, but it is not showing the data I want, it shows basically everything. I will try another function than just `Now()`

Comment: changing `uedate = Now()` to `uedate = Date` and using `"<" & cDbl(uedate)` worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few changes, the code looks like this.

```
Sub FilteringReport()
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\benesjan\Desktop\Benes_jan\Excel_VBA\test_file\preventive_report.xlsx"
        Workbooks("preventive_report.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
                
                
        'Todays date, or custom date
        If Workbooks("PMM_reports.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value = True Then
            edate = Workbooks("PMM_reports.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").Value
        Else
            edate = Date
        End If
                
        With Sheets("Sheet1")
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=""
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<" & CDbl(edate), Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=" & CDbl(edate)
        End With
 End Sub
```

Formating the `Now()` function caused the data to not filter correctly, by using `Date` function, I was able to make the filter work. Thanks *[Foxfire And Burns And Burns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9199828/foxfire-and-burns-and-burns)*